# getting undefined when trying to get a property from object passed as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react by making a simple todo app. I'm having a problem when trying to get a property value from an object passed as a prop from another component. I'm using PERN stack with bootstrap for my styling

I don't really know how to explain my problem but I hope someone could guide me. Here's my code

ListTodo.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa'
import Form from './Form'

const ListTodo = ({ list, onDelete }) => {


    return (
        <Fragment>
            
            <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">Activity</th>
                <th scope="col">When</th>
                <th scope="col">Reminder</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {/* <tr>  TEMPLATE FOR ROW LAYOUT
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Wew</td>
                <td>Chuchu</td>
                <td>we</td>
                </tr> */}

                {list.map(todo => (
                    <tr key={todo.todo_id}>
                    <td>{todo.activity}</td>
                    <td>{todo.date_time}</td>
                    <td>{todo.reminder ? "YES" : "NO"}</td>
                    <td><Form purpose="EDIT" data={todo} text="Edit To Do" /></td>
                    <td><FaTimes onClick={() => onDelete(todo.todo_id)} /></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default ListTodo
```

Form.js

```
import React, { Fragment} from 'react'
import { FaPlus, FaEdit } from 'react-icons/fa'

const Form = ({ purpose, data }) => {

console.log(data)

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {purpose === "EDIT" ? <FaEdit data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" /> : <FaPlus data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop" />}


            <div className="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    
                    <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Here's what I get when trying to console log the object received on Form.js

I hope someone could help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: What does the data in `list` look like?

Comment: Hi, here's what the data in list look like


[{"todo_id":4,"activity":"Go to HILL","date_time":"SATURDAY 11:30AM","reminder":true},{"todo_id":5,"activity":"Go to YOO","date_time":"HELLo 11:30AM","reminder":false},{"todo_id":6,"activity":"Go to Whammy","date_time":"sadlfjk 11:30AM","reminder":true},{"todo_id":7,"activity":"Go to MANOK","date_time":"sljsdhf 11:30AM","reminder":false}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just made a dummy list to run your code. Your code run without any errors.

[Please check with this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-proskuriakova-8grz2?file=/src/Form.js)

So what exactly problems do you want to ask ?

Comment: Thanks, I just solved my problem. The problem was from my main component. I tried to call the Form.js component and it's passing blank values to the props thus returning undefined.